# Is notifiy_one()/notify_all() semantically a release-operation, and if yes, where is that defined?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, condition-variable, memory-barriers

Consider the following example from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable):

```
std::mutex m;
std::condition_variable cv;
std::string data;
bool ready = false;
bool processed = false;
 
void worker_thread()
{
    // Wait until main() sends data
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
    cv.wait(lk, []{return ready;});
 
    // after the wait, we own the lock.
    std::cout << "Worker thread is processing data\n";
    data += " after processing";
 
    // Send data back to main()
    processed = true;
    std::cout << "Worker thread signals data processing completed\n";
 
    // Manual unlocking is done before notifying, to avoid waking up
    // the waiting thread only to block again (see notify_one for details)
    lk.unlock();
    cv.notify_one();
}
 
int main()
{
    std::thread worker(worker_thread);
 
    data = "Example data";
    // send data to the worker thread
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m);
        ready = true;
        std::cout << "main() signals data ready for processing\n";
    }
    cv.notify_one();
 
    // wait for the worker
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
        cv.wait(lk, []{return processed;});
    }
    std::cout << "Back in main(), data = " << data << '\n';
 
    worker.join();
}
```

It is said that notification can and even should be done after releasing the lock. However, I fail to understand how this still provides enough safety regarding the memory order.

Through what mechanism can it be guaranteed that the change of the boolean flag is visible to the other thread by the time that it receives the notification?

I can't find anything that says that notify_one() is in and of itself a release-operation in terms of acquire-release semantics. Thus, it seems to that we cannot be sure that the change in the flag actually happens-before the reception of the notification, and therefore the compiler might even decide to reorder the notification into the preceding mutex-protected block (reordering an instruction from after the unlock to before the lock (!) should not usually "break the contract"), so that the notification is received before the updated flag is observed, and the other thread might wait forever.

In other words: Where in the standard does it say that notify_one "synchronizes-with" receiving a notification?

EDIT: The related question [How is std::atomic<T>::notify_all ordered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62295310/how-is-stdatomictnotify-all-ordered) differs in that it is about the notify_() functions of C++20 atomic and the standard excerpts quoted therein do not apply to condition variables, and as such cannot be considered an answer to my question which is specifically about the standard wording related to CVs and their ordering/timing.
The actual answer is likely given by this paragraph of the standard:

http://eel.is/c++draft/thread.condition#4

Comment: If you notify after you release the lock, and you release the lock after you modify the flag, then the notified thread cannot access the flag until after the lock is released which implies it cannot access the flag until the flag has been modified. Note that a thread waiting on a conditon_variable may spontaneously exit the wait function without being notified.

Comment: Unless, the compiler reorders the notification to happen before the acquiry of the lock, which it might do, because by the letter-of-the law, that does not break the ordering-guarantees provided, as far as I am aware (which has to be wrong, but I'm interested in learning where in the standard it says that I am wrong)

Comment: Can that reorder even happen? Even so, the waiting thread can't exit the wait (even spontaneously) until the lock is freed. Exiting the wait REQUIRES acquiring the lock.

Comment: That is basically the  crux of my question: What prevents that reorder? I stated the problem incorrectly, the situation I am considering is that the notify gets reordered before the entire mutex-protected block, not merely before the release.

Comment: Compilers will generally not reorder statements to the other side of a function call with side effects, unless it can prove by the as-if rule that the side effects combined with the reordering will not affect observable behavior. I would expect mutex lock/unlock and notify/wait to be sufficiently opaque to the compiler (implemented in an external library is about as opaque as you can get) that it will not swap their order as it would be unable to prove the behavior to be identical in both cases.

Comment: The same lack of a clear guarantee in the standard was the subject of [How is std::atomic::notify\_all ordered?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62298800).  I haven't read your example code very carefully; I think you're worried about notify_all sneaking into the earlier critical section (i.e. the unlock release-operation becoming visible after the notify_all), in which case it's the same question.  If there are parts of your question that aren't a duplicate, please edit to link to that other question and highlight what you're asking that isn't covered there.

Comment: The TL:DR seems to be: from a language-lawyer POV, I think there's a problem of under-specified ordering of `notify` operations.  From a practical POV, no real compiler could plausibly reorder that way; any sane implementation will make sure it can't, e.g. by making it a non-inline function call.

Comment: The question is related but the difference is that it is specifically about c++20 atomic waits, its accepted answer doesn't answer my question because it is exactly the lack of information about how notify() of CVs (as opposed to c++20 atomics) relates to the happens-before relation referred to in the accepted answer, that is the core of my question. In other words: It doesn't answer my question because it is not about condition variables.

Comment: http://eel.is/c++draft/thread.condition#4 This provides the actual answer to my question. The notification and the steps of the wait and wakeup operations happen in a single total order consistent with the happens-before relation. As far as I understand, this guarantees that by the time the waiting thread observes the notification it must also observe the setting of the flag, as it happens-before the call to notify.

Comment: Didn't see your reply because you didn't @user tag me to notify.  Sorry, I missed you were asking about the existing `notify` on `std::condition_variable`, not the new C++20 feature.  Reopened.  Glad to hear ordering is better defined for that.